# Xcode 4.4 - Unable to add compiler flags to compile sources

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-flags

In Xcode 4.4 it seems I am unable to add compiler flags to individual source files. I am trying to [remove ARC from a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) but I can not get the pop up to add flags. Double clicking or selecting the item and pressing enter does not work, also tried selecting multiple and pushing enter which does not work. I have tried with two separate projects, one of which I created with Xcode 4.4. Is there another way to manually add compiler flags to a source file? (I do not have an older version of Xcode to see how it stores the value [likely in the pbxproj]).

Note: *MacBook Pro w/ Retina Display - OSX 10.8*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found where the window was hiding. I had to drag Xcode pretty far down to the lower left corner of my screen as the pop up window was showing up and to the right. This made it completely hidden while full screen.

[image: Screen Shot]

A bug report has been filed [rdar://11970271](http://openradar.appspot.com/11970271)

Comment: Did you report the bug?  bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @StephenCanon bug reported [rdar://11970271](http://openradar.appspot.com/11970271)

Comment: Exactly the same bug was driving me nuts, thanks for the follow up!

Comment: It's possible to interact with that hidden floating window. When you double click on the file, just type the flag you want to add and press return. The new flag shows up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.By the way, hide the utilities can also display Compiler Flags